# How to change "always on top" Window behavior dynamically in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.5

How can I change the behavior by e.g. toggling a `Menu` item? I tried changing/setting flags:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtWebEngine 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Private 1.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0
//(...)
property alias isOnTop: onTop.checked
flags: (isOnTop) ? (Qt.Window | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint) : (Qt.Window ) // not working
```

Flags are set properly but won't change when `onTop.checked` changes.

Comment: Don't you have to switch the order in your ternary operation? Like so: `flags: (isOnTop) ? (Qt.Window) : (Qt.Window | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)`

Comment: i think it's good. The problem is that it is not changing- it inits properly (checked by changing (isOnTop) to (!isOnTop) -both works as I expected)